# Difference between experimental unit and observation

Tags: r, predictive-models, experiment-design

In the design of experiment in Agricultural research (I seek in particular that of Plant Breeding), common practice is that each experimental unit corresponds to one observation in the dataset. But, is it possible to use each sample (samping is done within a plot) on its own as individual observation by adding another factor, to infer from the dataset?

For instance, In a alpha lattice design of experiment, I have following combination of factors and a response variables:

```
plots cols block     entries replication response
101    1     1  wheat_gen4           1    111.16131
102    2     1 wheat_gen11           1     73.51577
103    3     1  wheat_gen2           1    110.58604
104    4     1 wheat_gen16           1    117.10852
105    1     2 wheat_gen12           1    111.37657
106    2     2 wheat_gen13           1    105.00643
```

Apparently, `plots` column is the identifier for the experimental unit. We routinely model the data with one or more predictors (`cols`, `block`, `entries` and `replication`) and perform analysis of the `response`. But, although the data gathering process calls for obtaining multiple samples from each experimental units, we eventually end up having an average or a single summary value for all samples, as response variable.

So, What I wish to know here is, why are the individual samples themselves not the observation, but their summary is?
Say, for instance, I took five sample plants from each plot and thus want to also use that to model as response using this new structure. Does this require a new factor be introduced ? If so, how do I interpret the new factor?

Or am I conceptually wrong? Forgive, me for the ambiguities. I'm a beginner in design of experiments and computational statistics.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think an illustration of what you mean is needed to make this question clear enough to be answerable.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I'll update the question to make me more understandable.

Comment: If you have repeated observations from the same experimental unit (plot in your case), you can model this using Mixed Effects Models. They also allow modeling the nesting of plots in the blocks and other dependency structures. Everyone working with the kind of experimental setup you describe here should be familiar with (Linear) Mixed Effects Models, but sadly many are not.

Comment: Me having seen that you are an 'R' enthusiast and a person of life sciences career, can you refer me to some illustrations of analysis employing Mixed Models relevant to the field?

Comment: This is a good introduction: http://www.highstat.com/book2.htm

Comment: also look into pseudo replication